# Organisms with the most extreme sensory capabilities? (sight, smell, sound)

Tags: neuroscience, zoology, neuroanatomy, sensation, perception

**Background**

It is quite mind boggling to imagine what it would be like to be missing sight, sound, touch, smell, taste etc.

**Question**

> Which organism holds the record for most extreme sensory limits for: sight, smell and sound? (one for each)

This would help give an idea of the "biological limits" of sense.

Comment: I believe this is too broad. There is a plethora of various kinds of neural sensors in animals, ranging from electric impulses to ultraviolet vision. Listing them all down might not be feasible.

Comment: hmm well this in itself was insightful thank you, I suppose if people list some nice sources to learn this kind of information would still be so helpful... in any case who says there is a limit to how many answers there can be...

Comment: @hello_there_andy Please read through [this section](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) of the Help Center - particularly *"Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."*

Comment: @MattDMo I see, cheers for that clarification I will edit it right away then